# Pandas shift logic

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe like:

```
col1 customer
 1    a
 3    a
 1    b
 2    b
 3    b
 5    b
```

I want the logic to be like this:

```
col1 customer  col2
 1    a         1
 3    a         1
 1    b         1
 2    b         2
 3    b         3
 5    b         3
```

as you can see, if the customer has consistent values in col1, give it, if not, give the last consistent number which is 3

I tried using the df.shift() but I was stuck

Further Example:

```
col1
1
1
1
3
5
8
10
```

he should be given a value of 1 because that's the last consistent value for him!

Comment: The logic is unclear, you don't really `shift` the values here. How do you define "consistent"? Can you break down the result?

Comment: why is your second output "b" value a 2 and not 1?

Comment: because the second value of 'b' is 2 and followed by a 3 which is consistent, and in the case of the last value of b, it's 5 which is not consistent with 3!

Comment: There is no customer in your new example. And you still don't define "*consistent*", how would you explain this term to a 5 year old?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

If you have more than one month, you can use this version:

```
import numpy as np

inc_count = lambda x: np.where(x.diff(1) == 1, x, x.shift(fill_value=x.iloc[0]))
df['col2'] =  df.groupby('customer')['col1'].transform(inc_count)
print(df)

# Output
   col1 customer  col2
0     1        a     1
1     3        a     1
2     1        b     1
3     2        b     2
4     3        b     3
5     5        b     3
```

---

Maybe you want to increment a counter if the next row value following the current one:

```
# Same as df['col1'].diff().eq(1).cumsum().add(1)
df['col2'] = df['col1'].eq(df['col1'].shift()+1).cumsum().add(1)
print(df)

# Output
   col1 customer  col2
0     1        a     1
1     3        a     1
2     1        b     1
3     2        b     2
4     3        b     3
5     5        b     3
```

Or for each customer:

```
inc_count = lambda x: x.eq(x.shift()+1).cumsum().add(1)
df['col2'] = df['col2'] = df.groupby('customer')['col1'].transform(inc_count)
print(df)

# Output
   col1 customer  col2
0     1        a     1
1     3        a     1
2     1        b     1
3     2        b     2
4     3        b     3
5     5        b     3
```

Comment: The idea is if the customer stopped buying at any month, the new column should be assigned with the last consistent value

Comment: In this case, this works for a year. I suppose col1 is month? And for December (12) and January (1)?

Comment: it's just a cohort for months, treated as a label

Comment: Can you provide a more real example?

Comment: I edited the question, please check it out

Comment: It kept adding numbers incrementally